# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'randint'

Tags: python-3.x, random, module, attributeerror

[I have a recent problem with random module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o68F5.png)

I dont understand why is that?
I showed the exact path that goes to random.py but it still didnt work.
python3.4 64bit
using pycharm 2016.2.2
First group is real error
Second group relates to help(random)
Sorry about confusion.

```
  File "C:/Users/blueg/Google Drive/Programming/Python/PycharmProjects/LearningPython/Random Module/random.py", line 1, in <module>
    import random     File "C:\Users\blueg\Google Drive\Programming\Python\PycharmProjects\LearningPython\Random Module\random.py", line 4, in <module>
    a = random.randint(1,6) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'randint'


Help on module random:
NAME random
FILE c:\users\blueg\google drive\programming\python\pycharmprojects\learningpython\random module\random.py
```

Comment: Post code and error messages as code-formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Code-formatted, not quote-formatted. Code formatting is the button with the braces on it.

Comment: Thanks for saying

Answer (score 1):

you have called your module `random.py` and thus you're importing your own module: rename it it will work (and also delete the `random.pyc` associated file or python will use that one in turn)

(I sometimes think that naming one's module in german, french or other avoids conflicts :))

Comment: Thanks for reply sir.But it didnt help :(

Comment: also delete the `random.pyc` associated file

Comment: I found the file in __pycache__ and deleted it.(full name: random.cpython-34.pyc)
After that code didnt work again. :( same error

Comment: You just deleted a python system file... Not a problem it will be regenerated. BTW I have an idea: rename it and *move it to another folder*. Run it from the command line (quit your editor) too. I'm 100% sure the problem is the name of your module.

Comment: i renamed "random.cpython-34.pyc" as "randomRENAMED.pyc"
and put it in a file in desktop.
From command prompt(as admin) i opened the file and :
__ImportError: No module named site__.


When i use idle,code works like magic.But with Pycharm editor,gives me an error.